# AngularJs how to check if a value exist in an array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I am trying to loop through an array to check if *email, phone* and *alternate phone* exist in database my issue is I can't find any function or work around in Angularjs that can help me loop through the array where I have set the the listed through variable

```
$scope.dataCheck = {
email: $scope.TheEmail,
phone: $scope.ThePhone,
AltPhone: $scope.TheAltPhone
}
```

I have tried to use indexOf like below still not working

```
if ($scope.dataCheck.indexOf($scope.TheEmail)) {
//I call a function to check if email exist and return  
}
```

Thank You

> I should mention I am using ExpressJs and I am new to Javascript

Comment: `$scope.dataCheck` is not array.

Comment: well dataCheck is not an array... Objects do not have indexOf

Comment: Is `$scope.TheEmail` an array of emails? Which is the array?

Comment: `hasOwnProperty`, `typeof`, `in`.. There are some ways, learn Javascript.

Comment: What do you want to check= if an specific email is in the array, or if the array exists?

Comment: What do you mean by *"loop through"*?.... Nothing shown suggests a loop is needed. Explain what you are trying to do in words. Broken code is not a good substitute for an axplanation

Comment: Thank You all and Yep @dfsq I should have mention javascript is new to me sorry I skip that

Answer (score 3):

While you are technically correct that objects in JavaScript are associative arrays, they are not Arrays as such. Compare the object property to the value you are searching for.

```
$scope.dataCheck = {
  email: $scope.TheEmail,
  phone: $scope.ThePhone,
  AltPhone: $scope.TheAltPhone
}

if ($scope.dataCheck.email === $scope.TheEmail) {
  //I call a function to check if email exist and return  
}
```

If you simply want to see if the has *a* value, you can check

```
if (typeof $scope.dataCheck.email !== "undefined") { ... }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if (myArray.filter(x => !x.TheEmail || !x.ThePhone ||  !x.TheAltPhone).length == 0) {
    // do something
}
```

if a value is undefined, null or empty ("") javascript will return false. Filter function will return values which contains the expression and count them with length without loop through all items.

about filter you can find here more information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter?v=control

Hope this helps.

Comment: it's an object...not an array. Can't use `filter()` on an object

Comment: my fault I use `$scope.dataCheck` as variable, however in your first line there is mentioned he loops through an array, in this case I assume he can use that array instead of $scope.dataCheck. Also updated code.

Comment: see first line (not the code): `I am trying to loop through an array to check if email, phone an.....`

Comment: Fine...now look at the code...do you see an array anywhere?

Comment: Think out of the box, if you could use filter the other code what is written will be obsolete. What I try here is to show how it could solved another way without using his code.

Comment: Your out of the box concept will simply confuse the OP...There is no indication of any proper array! You have made no mention of that fact

Comment: because he hasn't written an array does not means there is no array. I assume that I there is an array because he mentioned it in his post. I this will confuse him or her let ask himself for more information or does not want to use this code will be also fine. On the other side maybe he will be satisfied with this approach,  why bother this you?

Comment: Because you haven't given any indication that it can not be used on the code shown. Based on what is shown this answer is simply wrong and misleading

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143091/discussion-between-hakany-and-charlietfl).